# IntelliSense keeps giving [Failure] Could not find a part of the path C:\TEMP

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

After changing my temporary folder, I got an issue with IntelliSense in VS2015 complaining it cannot find the temp folder (other applications, including VS2015, find the new location just fine).

The error I receive after firing up a project (seems to happen with any type of solution, C#, ASP.NET etc) is repeatedly this message in the output window of Visual Studio 2015:

[image]

```
[Failure] Could not find a part of the path 'R:\TMP\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find a part of the path 'R:\TMP\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find a part of the path 'R:\TMP\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find a part of the path 'R:\TMP\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find a part of the path 'R:\TMP\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find a part of the path 'R:\TMP\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find a part of the path 'R:\TMP\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
```

I think I replaced all rogue references to the `R:\TMP` location in the registry, but this one remains. Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Abel, please try to remove or delete the folders: C:\Users\<your users name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 and C:\Users\<your users name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0. Delete the .suo file in your project folder and start the VS to open your project to rebuild it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Exit Visual Studio
2. Delete all non-project files (bin, obj. .vs, _ReSharper.Caches folders, *.suo files, ...)
3. Start VS and rebuild

That fixed it for me.

Comment: I have tried to delete the bin and obj folders but this could not help. When I deleted the suo files it worked again, thanks!

Comment: Deleting the .vs folder fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Related but maybe not exactly answering this question.

I had this issue but realized that the error message couldn't find `v4.x.0`, so I changed the filename in the `AppData/Local/TEMP/` directory as well as the versions inside the code. Then I had another error saying it was missing `v4.y.0`. So, I copied the original file and had two files with both names and code pointing to both versions. I then ran the Clean Solution command and Rebuild command, restarted VS and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to: 
 **Build**,
than select:
 **Rebuild Solution**
 ... As easy as that...

Comment: If it only were true, that was the first thing I tried. The message kept coming back. But as already answered, it's a problem with the .vs folder, containing localized settings. Delete that and it solves the issue.