# Can't Publish ASP.NET Project Because Of One Of My ASPX Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, publish

I wanted to publish my project with "PreCompile During Publish" option checked but I get this error:

> Copying file VERYLONGDIRECTORY\P.aspx to obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\VERYLONGDIRECTORY\P.aspx failed. Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\VERYLONGDIRECTORY\P.aspx'.

I deleted the file from the project and the publish succeeded. Then, re-added the ASPX file to the project and the error is popping up again. I excluded it from the project and it works. I need the ASPX file to be in my project, this is a bit weird...

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try put the following in your publish profile (.pubxml)

`<aspnetcompilemergeintermediateoutputpath>c:\temp</aspnetcompilemergeintermediateoutputpath>`

This will change the temporary path where the project is built.
Windows has a max length of 260 characters for file path.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the answer.

It worked.

So, why is there a need of this tag in the profile?

Comment: This will change the temporary path where the project is built

Comment: Hi @Jefferson Raposo. Sorry for the late response. Yeah, I got that. I meant what is actually the problem? Should VS developers fix it or something? I was just curious to know why this temporary path is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me that the above exception was copied and pasted for this question?
Because, I could find a Typo in the exception which is given below:
Copying file VERYLONGDIRECTORY\P.aspx to obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\VERYLONGDIRECTORY\P.aspx.aspx failed ,this line ends with dual P.aspx.aspx extension. This typo would be a reason if not then do check some links below.

I have provided some links related to your exception, If you have not already visited, then do check their are multiple solutions and you could find one.

[IntelliSense keeps giving [Failure] Could not find a part of the path C:\TEMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953569/intellisense-keeps-giving-failure-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-c-temp)

[ASP.NET publish trying to copy a non-existant file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705550/asp-net-publish-trying-to-copy-a-non-existant-file)

Comment: Hello there. Yes, the filename was so long and while I was replacing the name, I added the format again so yeah, that's a typo.

Comment: I had already tried those. @Jefferson Raposo's answer helped.